# Can I use an IN clause with a LEFT JOIN clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

FORE NOTE: This question regards the IN clause that belongs in the FROM statement and lets you reference to an external database. Do not confuse this with the IN statements that might live in a WHERE clause, please.

Version: MS Access 2016

External table is on the local network

The crux of what I am trying to do is grab an [Employee] table from an external ACCDB database and LEFT JOIN it to a local [Employees] (note the 's') table. I am trying to generate a list of (non-terminated) employees that are not yet added to my local [Employees] table. As in:

```
SELECT Employee.Last_Name, Employee.First_Name, Employee.Job_Title
FROM Employee IN "\\{full path}\Time Clock 1.0_be.accdb" 
LEFT JOIN Employees
ON Employee.Last_Name = Employees.LastName
AND Employee.First_Name = Employees.FirstName
WHERE Employees.FirstName IS NULL
AND Employee.Termination_Date = ""
ORDER BY Employee.Last_Name, Employee.First_Name;
```

Only the above SQL doesn't work. Access gives me the ever-so-not-very helpful `Syntax error in FROM clause` to brighten my neurotic insanity.

Does the IN clause have to go last and does it effect both tables? At:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177907(v=office.12).aspx

they say it can be combined with a LEFT JOIN but they don't specify if both tables must be external.

Can you even LEFT JOIN a table from an external DB to an local table? I don't really want to link the table formally as this query will only run occasionally and I don't want any more traffic pinging the Time Clock back end DB than I have to. It's slow enough as it is.

Comment: Try `... FROM [\\{full path}\Time Clock 1.0_be.accdb].Employee ...`

Comment: Why don't you just create a separate external query for the `Employee IN "\\{full path}\Time Clock 1.0_be.accdb"` and refer to it? Or, even better, why not create a linked table?

Comment: @Gord Thompson That seems like an easier way to reference external tables. Making it a nested SELECT statement made the original error go away but now it gives me the error *Cannot reference a table with a multi-valued field using a FROM clause that refers to another database*. Reminder to everyone to never succumb to the temptation to avoid a linking table by using a multi-valued field. Curse my predecessors >:(. I _really_ didn't want to have to create a linked table but I am starting to see the writing on the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to my original question:

@cha was right to suggest I use nested queries. This solves the problem of an internal table being joined to an external table.

@Gord Thompson had a much more specific way of referencing to an external DB that seems clearer to me than the IN clause in this simple case. Programmers may want to use the IN clause when connecting to different *types* of external databases as it gives you the ability to specify all that in the IN clause.

In the end none of this helped me because the train-wreck-of-a-database I lovingly caress uses multi-value fields and Access **will not** link an internal table with multi-valued fields to an external table.

Those who come after you (and probably you yourself) will thank you for observing 1st 2nd and 3rd normal forms except in the most unusual and carefully considered cases and for **never ever ever ever** using multi-valued fields instead of linking tables for many-to-many relationships.

Aloha!